# How to avoid ModeState invalid property error from appearing in the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a hidden field in a View:

```
<input asp-for="CreatedOnUtc" type="hidden"/>
```

Now, when the model state is invalid the following message is shown:

[image]

What I would like to do is to remove the error, it's only there because this is a partial view which is shared by an `Edit` and a `Create`, its goal it to keep the field only if it's in an `Edit` view but it has this unfortunate side effect when it's in the `Create` view.

I could add a dummy value in the controller when the model state is invalid, and the view is returned with the previous model, this would work:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    //do stuff
    RedirectToAction(...);
}
model.CreatedOnUtc = DateTime.MinValue;
return View(model);
```

But I was wondering if there is a nicer way of simply removing the model error. Note that I need to really remove the error because the Model set in the View must not be invalidated by that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (ModelState.ContainsKey("CreatedOnUtc")) ModelState["CreatedOnUtc"].Errors.Clear();
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  .....your code
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea, clearing the key regardless, yesterday it was late and I wasn't thinking very straight I guess. Well done. I guess it's a more elegant solution.